# jQuery animate - making slideshow image loop iterately in the same direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to make my own slideshow using jQuery. Here I got stuck with the direction of the slider image. I want it to loop only one direction ( right to left ). Please see my code Below:

HTML:

```
<div class="flash-banner">
    <ul>
       <li>
          <img src="img/flash-banner.jpg" alt="Black glass banner " />
       </li>
       <li>
          <img src="img/flash-banner-contact.jpg" alt="Black glass banner " />
       </li>
       <li>
          <img src="img/flash-banner-our-work.jpg" alt="Black glass banner " />
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function ( e ) {
    slideshow( 6000 );
});

function slideshow( speed ) {
    // Get width from image
    $pic = $('.flash-banner ul li img')[0];
    $width = $pic.width;

    // Count the total number of children of UL 
    $count = $('.flash-banner ul').children().length;

    // Set width to UL  
    var $ul = $width * $count;
    $('.flash-banner ul').css('width', $ul);
    var i = 1;

    setInterval( function ( e ) {
        if ( i > $count - 1 ) {
              // I think the problem is here, but I can't fix it
           i = 0;
           var b = 0;
        } else {
           var b = $width * i;
        }
        console.log( b );
        $element = $('.flash-banner ul');
        $element.animate(
           {'margin-left': -b },
           { duration: speed },
           { delay: speed }
        );
        i++;
    }, speed );
}
```

I also made a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/FzDtD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearInterval()` to stop the animation instead of resetting `i` to 0.

If you want to reloop the animation, call `.stop()` to stop it, fix the css to move the banner back to the original position and call the animation function again.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FzDtD/4/)

Alternatively, you can try just stopping the animation and resetting all values to the initial state, but I find that can get messy sometimes since you need to manually ensure that you reset all variables for this to work right.

Comment: In this case, it stops the loop. I wanted them to loop repeatedly. Thanks

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn: So you just want the animation to jump to the beginning when it reaches the end without 'sliding'?

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn: Updated with new jsfiddle